# How run delete queries via GraphDB REST API

Tags: rest, sparql, graphdb

I'm trying to run DELETE queries from the GraphDB REST API with Python requests module, without luck.

SELECT queries with `requests.get()` work fine:

```
query = "http://localhost:7200/repositories/myreponame?name=&infer=true&sameAs=false&query=SELECT%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20.%0A%7D%0A"
response = requests.get(query, headers = {"Authorization" : token})
```

But whenever I switch to a DELETE query, it won't work.

If I use the DELETE query with `requests.get()` I get this error:

```
query = "http://localhost:7200/repositories/myreponame?name=&infer=true&sameAs=false&query=DELETE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20.%0A%7D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20.%0A%7D%0A"

MALFORMED QUERY: Encountered " "delete" "DELETE "" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
    "base" ...
    "prefix" ...
    "select" ...
    "construct" ...
    "describe" ...
    "ask" ...
```

If I use the DELETE query with `requests.delete()` instead, I get:

```
Repository delete error: query supplied with request
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm accessing the API with admin privileges, so that is not the issue.

**EDIT:**
Based on UninformedUser's comment I tried the switching to a POST request, and modifying the URL from **query** to **update**. Also added the appropriate content type as described [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-protocol/#update-operation):

```
query = "http://localhost:7200/repositories/myreponame?name=&infer=true&sameAs=false&update=DELETE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20.%0A%7D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20.%0A%7D%0A"
response = requests.post(query, headers = {"Authorization" : token, "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
```

Now getting the following error:

```
Missing parameter: query
```

Comment: you can't use a `GET` request for SPARQL Update statements like `DELETE`, you have to make a `POST` request. Also the param is usually `update` then and not `query`, see the protocol specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-protocol/#update-operation

Comment: Thanks, this helped a bit, but I'm still not getting it to work. Please see edit in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I was missing a specific requirement from GraphDB: for updates it's necessary to append `/statements` right after the repository ID:

```
query = "http://localhost:7200/repositories/myreponame/statements?name=&infer=true&sameAs=false&update=DELETE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20.%0A%7D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20.%0A%7D%0A"
response = requests.post(query, headers = {"Authorization" : token, "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
```